# How to write custom PHPUnit assertion that behaves like built-in assertion?

Tags: phpunit, assertion

How can I write a custom assertion, like `assertFoo($expected, $actual)`, that behaves like the built-in assertions with respect to the error "stack trace"?

I currently have the following method defined (within a class that extends `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`):

```
public static function assertFoo($expected, $actual) {
    self::assertEquals($expected, $actual); 
}
```

If I call this from a test and the test fails, I get two items in the call stack:

```
1) PreferencesTest::testSignupTeacher
Failed asserting that 5 matches expected 3.

/vagrant/myproject/tests/integration/PreferencesTest.php:17
/vagrant/myproject/tests/integration/PreferencesTest.php:136
```

Line 17 is where `assertFoo()` calls the built-in `assertEquals()` and fails; line 136 is there `assertFoo()` is called.

If I change the test to call `assertEquals()` directly, I only get one:

```
1) PreferencesTest::testSignupTeacher
Failed asserting that 3 is true.

/vagrant/myproject/tests/integration/PreferencesTest.php:136
```

There's some [documentation in the manual](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.custom-assertions), but it doesn't seem to cover this.

Comment: Can you show the code for your assertFoo() function.

Answer (score 4):

My first guess of the problem (that you're not using one of the `PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_*` objects and `self::assertThat`) turned out to be completely irrelevant! The actual answer is that phpUnit helpfully filters away from the stack trace anything in its own codebase, and just leaves functions in user space!

The code that does this can be found in */path/to/PHPUnit/Util/Filter.php* (where */path/to/* is */usr/share/php* on my machine) and the functions of interest are `getFilteredStacktrace` and `isFiltered`.

If you'd like to control this behaviour, then put your custom asserts into a class derived from `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`, then derive your tests from that class. In your custom class file put a call somewhere to `addFileToFilter`, as shown here:

```
class My_Base_TestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{
  public static function assertFoo($expected, $actual) {
    self::assertEquals($expected, $actual); 
  }
}

PHPUnit_Util_Filter::addFileToFilter(__FILE__, 'DEFAULT');
```

Then in another file you have:

```
class CustomTest extends My_Base_TestCase{

  /** */
  public function testSomething2(){
    $this->assertFoo( 8,  5+4 );
  }
}
```

and it will behave just like the built-in `assertEquals()`.

DISCLAIMER: This is using undocumented behaviour! I'll try and find out if this mechanism is going to be reasonably future-proof.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like `PHPUnit_Util_Filter::addFileToFilter()` disappeared in 3.5.  The 3.6 way seems to use `PHPUnit_Util_GlobalState::phpunitFiles()` to figure which files to remove, which is static static static all the way… I can't see any way to modify the behaviour `PHPUnit_Util_Filter::getFilteredStacktrace()` in 3.6.

Comment: @mjs Ha! Not at all future-proof then, sorry!! I should've said I was looking at phpUnit 3.4.5. If I get chance I'll take a look with latest phpUnit tomorrow.

Comment: Turns out in PHPUnit 6, you have to do `\PHPUnit\Util\Blacklist::$blacklistedClassNames['My_Base_TestCase'] = 1;`