# What does this phpunit function addFileToFilter function mean?

Tags: php, phpunit

I want to know what this line is trying to do.

```
PHPUnit_Util_Filter::addFileToFilter(__FILE__, 'PHPUNIT');
```

The code down below belongs to PHPUNIT [manual](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/phpunit-book.html#). Truth is, I got a "method not found" on "addFileToFilter", if anyone can help me with that as well, it would be so much appreciated.

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPUnit/Util/Filter.php';

require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/Database/DataSet/AbstractDataSet.php';
require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/Database/DataSet/DefaultTableIterator.php';
require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/Database/DataSet/DefaultTable.php';
require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/Database/DataSet/DefaultTableMetaData.php';

PHPUnit_Util_Filter::addFileToFilter(__FILE__, 'PHPUNIT');

class MyApp_DbUnit_ArrayDataSet extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_AbstractDataSet
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $tables = array();

    /**
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        foreach ($data AS $tableName => $rows) {
            $columns = array();
            if (isset($rows[0])) {
                $columns = array_keys($rows[0]);
            }

            $metaData = new PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_DefaultTableMetaData($tableName, $columns);
            $table = new PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_DefaultTable($metaData);

            foreach ($rows AS $row) {
                $table->addRow($row);
            }
            $this->tables[$tableName] = $table;
        }
    }

    protected function createIterator($reverse = FALSE)
    {
        return new PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_DefaultTableIterator($this->tables, $reverse);
    }

    public function getTable($tableName)
    {
        if (!isset($this->tables[$tableName])) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("$tableName is not a table in the current database.");
        }

        return $this->tables[$tableName];
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a version conflict / installation issue.

pear version should produce 1.9.4.. If not pear upgrade and follow the commands until it does.

Then `sudo pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/phpunit` to fix the installation.+

Your include path should include the "pear" dir. Use pear config-show to find that.

Original: ["Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Filter::addfiletofilter() in /usr/bin/phpunit on line 48"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241183/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-phpunit-util-filteraddfiletofilter-in)

Comment: I install phpunit by composer. Can I still do it this way. And I really want to know what this line of code is for. Can I just comment that out?

Comment: I think the core problem is probably a version mismatch. You should try to upgrade to a newer/closer, or use the matching documentation.

Comment: Maybe I was wrong with the upgrading. Here they say this has been phased out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746212/how-to-write-custom-phpunit-assertion-that-behaves-like-built-in-assertion/11769835#11769835 Anyway the version mismatch seems to probable.